# Get List Item URL (fileURL- Server Relative URL)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I have a list created in SharePoint. Now I want a server relative url (list item URL- i.e. "`http://server/site/list/<listname>/file1.xml`") using C#. How can I get it?

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: did you do any research? It's always sitecollection/Lists/ListName or Sitecollection/Site/Lists/ListName in case of DocumentLibraries the /Lists/ is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite("http://server/sites/Contoso"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = siteCol.RootWeb)
    {
         SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
         SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(8);
         string fileurl = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl];
    }
}
```

Excerpt from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521580%28v=office.14%29.aspx)